# Error to compile file PyObject (Gtk ) with Pydev

Tags: python-3.x, pyobject

I'm build application with pyobject (gtk) in Pydev , but i'm try to create a window 
the following way:

Class Ventana

```py
from gi.overrides import Gtk


class Ventana( Gtk.Window ):
   def __init__( self,titulo ):
      Gtk.Window.__init__(self,title=titulo )
      self.connect("delete-event",Gtk.main_quit )
```

Class Aplicacion( Main):

```py
def main():
    win = Ventana()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

but I'm try to compile te App, show the following mistake:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/demian/workspace/NidhugsRPG/nidhugs/presentacion/Consola.py", line 6, in      
<module>
from gi.overrides import Gtk
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/overrides/Gtk.py", line 35, in <module>
Gtk = modules['Gtk']._introspection_module
KeyError: 'Gtk'
```

I'm try use the import

```
 from gi.repository import Gtk
```

but, not works,because moudule not found.So i'm use the import:

```py
from gi.overrides import Gtk
```

¿How to fix my trouble?

Sorry for my bad English

Thanks.